# Does equating coefficients work in algebraically closed fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory

I am wondering the following: Does "equating coefficients" work over algebraically closed fields?

For example: Let $F$ be an algebraically closed field with $a,b \in F$. Can we argue that

$$a^6+2a^4+a^2 = b^6+2b^4+b^2$$

implies $a=b$?

Comment: What if $a=-b$?

Comment: Why would you call those "*coefficients*"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can only happen if your expression is "injective". For example, as said in the comments, consider $\mathbb{C}$, then if
$$
a^2 = b^2
$$
this doesnt imply that $a=b$ since $a$ can be $1$ and $b = -1 $